# Pycharm. Switch off hierarchy/navigation bar

Tags: pycharm

After upgrading to 2017 version, new hierarchy bar appeared:[image]

How to switch it off?
There is no name for this bar in "View" options, so I even don't know how to search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's breadcrumbs.

You can switch them off in `File - Settings - Editor - General - Appearance - Show breadcrumbs`.